# Is it okay to add userId to a DTO object?

Tags: architecture, dto

I'm implementing the validation layer for a certain method on a controller, namely I need to check if certain image `ids` passed do really belong to the user making a request. In order to do that I need to retrieve the `userId` from the `jwt` and then execute a DB query. The problem is that I need to know that `userId`, unfortunately it's impossible to access request context from the validation class and I came up with the idea of writing an interceptor that would intercept the auth header, retrieve `userId` from there and then attach it to the DTO. So my DTO will look something like this:

```
export class DeleteImagesDto implements Identifiable {
    @ApiProperty({ isArray: true })
    @IsArray()
    @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
    @Validate(IsOwnImages)
    ids: number[];

    userId: number;
}
```

and the interface looks as follows:

```
export interface Identifiable {
    userId: number;
}
```

`IsOwnImages` is the validation class (a provider) containing all the validation logic.

This additional field won't appear in the documentation (cos it's not decorated appropriately) and it won't be validated, so it looks somewhat alright but I personally don't like this implicit parameter juggling, it looks like I'm implementing some dirty functionality, writing a hack. that's to say, now the DTO contains some vague extra field that doesn't come directly from the request body. Or I am wrong? I just can't come up with a valid case where this hack may backfire in the future...

I would appreciate your opinion.

EDIT:

The one who downvoted the question, you're free to explain your frustrations. What was it? Bad day at work?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be OK?

Comment: @RobertHarvey well in my opinion it sort of obfuscates DTO, I think it should contain only those fields that come directly from the request body. It's just based on the idea of making stuff as explicit as possible/reasonable.

Comment: If you add an additional field to a class which has a different role than the other fields, than this special field should have *extra* documentation about its special role. Lack of documentation is what looks "hackish" to me, not adding the field.

Comment: @DocBrown Oh yeah I completely agree with what you said regarding documentation, I meant to say the swagger documentation, so that it doesn't confuse the client, cos the client doesn't have to know anything about this field. But of course this functionality must be documented, but in a different way. I will do it this way then. Thank you.

Comment: `userId` is a legit member of the validation process, alienating it won't do any good.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain agree, but the whole thing is about the way of passing it.

Comment: In other words I'm not saying it should be alienated, I'm wondering as to in which way it should not.

Comment: User IDs are routinely sent and returned in service calls.

Answer (score 2):

Adding user ID to DTO does not mean you will get the same user ID from the client. The only reliable way to get user ID is to retrieve retrieve it from the authentication info.

In my opinion, your validation is not quite good. Put in the validation class only the tasks that can be done without any other information. For instance, validate if the arguments are valid numbers (you do that in another annotation). The validation where you need user ID should be better done in the body of the method. From the body you can call a validation logic and pass all needed parameters including user ID.

**TLDR:** Remove `@Validate(IsOwnImages)` and call validation explicitly where you needed it.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The point of having the validation layer is that it saves you from trashing all your methods with validation logic, no matter how simple or complex it is, that's to say all your methods work with valid data only. In other words...it's like giving food to a baby, you feed it with good food only, well at least you separate the food from the package before putting it in a babies' mouth.

Comment: @Albert: *trashing all your methods with validation logic* - So you prefer 100 time more complex logic? You call *trashing* making logic 100 time simpler? There are many developers who read some idea and apply it everywhere without thinking at all, if it makes any sense in particular context. Such developers don't think of costs, of maintainability, of extensibility etc. Such approach is wrong. If you follow the approach described in OP, you will produce incredibly complex logic, which will be extremely error prone, it will have huge costs for small customer requirements.

Comment: @Albert: ... Your example actually confirms the solution I suggested. If you follow the approach described in the OP, you will require that the package contains information about the name of your baby, and if this particular package is suitable for your baby.

Comment: @Albert I would rather trash my methods with validation logic than trash the entire design of the system with unnecessary, black-box logic. Mentallurg's answer is far better than your option and, considering your -very weird- requisites, a good way to tackle the issue.

Comment: @mentallurg you do realise that the validation logic can be quite complex, right? And you're seriously considering that putting all that logic into a methods body will make it less error prone? I do reasonably doubt it. Less error prone also means more readable. One of the reasons why smart people out there came up with the idea of separating validation from business logic is because if you have to change your validation you won't have to change your method that you can potentially eff up. Your methods don't. have to know ANYTHING about whether they are processing valid or invalid data.

Comment: @mentallurg It's not their responsibility.

Comment: @T.Sar His solution doesn't comply well with SRP which sort of states that a class, or a function etc should have only one reason to change. In your words, it's a very weird solution that may lead to a very weird, hard-to-reproduce/hard-to-debug bugs.

Comment: Nah seriously, this solution is what should be avoided by any means possible. Not saying my option is good, if it were all good I wouldn't be here asking this question in the first place.

Comment: @Albert: All examples that you name actually confirm *my* approach and contradict to *your* statements :)
You say *doesn't comply well with SRP*. Wrong. My approach *does* follow SRP. I suggest that validator knows DTO attributes only. The only reason to extend DTO is, that the client needs to send more attributes. But the client does not modify user ID and thus does not need to send it. And service knows user ID from the context. Thus you have 2 reasons to modify DTO. Do you name it SRP compliant?

Comment: In my approach the validator has a *single* responsibility: Validation of DTO attributes without any additional information.
For instance, *lattitide* must be within the range [-90, 90], *longitude* must be within the range [-180, 180], etc.
Such validator can be tested in isolation from any other classes. It requires only DTO. This is a clean simple design.

Comment: Having validations does not mean that *all* validations should be done by a *single* validator. Think of compiler. How many different kinds of validations are there. 1) Syntax validations: check that all parentheses are correctly opened and closed, etc. 2) References: Check that all class names can be resolved. 3) Scope: Check that all references objects are reachable from the scope where they are used. 4) Check that all peaces of code are reachable. 5) Check that all variables in the expressions are of valid types, or that they can be cast to some type that leads to some reasonable result...

Comment: Or would you say that compilers don't follow SRP in such cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122921/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-albert).

Comment: @Albert  SRP is a guideline, not a law. If you follow it blindly, you're sure to hit a wall.

Comment: @Albert: _"The point of having the validation layer is that it saves you from trashing all your methods with validation logic"_ The issue here is that different methods may have different validation rules, and by putting the validation in the DTO, you effectively state that every DTO only has _one true way_ of being validated. Now, in the case of `DeleteImagesDto` it might be sufficiently correct because there's only one use case for it, but you need to consider your codebase at large. A specific validation rule belongs to the logic more than the DTO itself.

Comment: @Albert: Thinking of it another way, you use validation because you don't trust the DTO by itself. Therefore, it makes little sense to then start relying on a validation performed by this same untrustworthy DTO. Think like you're a police officer. Are you going to let the suspect also be the source of validating their own identity or information? No. You rely on a trusted source (the police database, or in your case an internal validation rule) which the suspect could not possibly have tampered with because they had no access to it; to confirm that the suspect's information (DTO) is valid.

Comment: @Flater Your analogy also shows why it is extremely hard to get authorities to be accountable for their own misdeeds!

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is that I need to know that userId, unfortunately it's impossible to access request context from the validation class and I came up with the idea of writing an interceptor that would intercept the auth header, retrieve userId from there and then attach it to the DTO.

Rather than attaching it to the DTO, I'm more inclined to make this interceptor an injectable dependency. In this approach, you don't pollute your DTO since the userId is not a field that should be passed in by the consumer.

***Edit** Based on the comment I received, I suspect the above explanation may not have been explicit enough that this injected dependency would not be injected on the DTO itself, but rather on the class which contains the logic which processes the passed DTO object. Since OP's code does not specifically show such an example, I used an imagined `ImagesService` class to showcase the example of a class which performs the deletion based on the`DeleteImagesDto` that is passed into it.*

Something along the lines of defining a service contract:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    string GetCurrentUserId();
}
```

Implementing that contract from a place where you have access to the HTTP context:

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string GetCurrentUserId()
    {
        // Your logic to retrieve the user ID from the context
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the dependency in your DI framework if you're using one.

And then you can do:

```
public class ImagesService
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

    public ImagesService(ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }

    public void DeleteImages(DeleteImagesDto data)
    {
        var currentUserId = _currentUserService.GetCurrentUser();

        foreach(int imageId in data.ids)
        {
            if(CanDeleteImage(imageId, currentUserId))
                DeleteImage(imageId);
        }
    }

    private bool CanDeleteImage(int imageId, string userId)
    {
        // Whatever logic you use to check if it's allowed
        return true;
    }

    private void DeleteImage(int imageId)
    {
        // Whatever logic you use to delete the image
    }
}
```

This is a basic example with some demo logic, you can of course implement your own logic as you see fit.

Note that I would implement this a bit more elegantly, but I chose this example as it's the most readable. Personally, I would refactor this into a more elegant variant using a separate validator class and LINQ instead of `foreach if`.

But since your question is light on concrete code examples (for the logic itself) and it seems you're a Java dev and not a C# dev, I intentionally opted for the simplest and most readable example to keep things short and clear.

---

As a side note, having a `ICurrentUserService` dependency is also really nice when writing unit tests that revolve around user identification.
I also use it during local development, using a `MockedCurrentUserService` class which returns a hardcoded user ID, so I don't have to actually log in or provide a JWT for simple debug runs. But those are tangential to the question at hand.

Comment: Shoving a dependency inside a DTO via a DI framework is no different from passing it as a bread-and-butter parameter, just less maintenable and worse to debug. He has a business logic problem that shouldn't be nowhere near the DTO.

Comment: @T.Sar: I actually 100% agree with you, but it seems you missed the part where this answer specifically _doesn't_ put it in the DTO (not the userid nor the dependency that gets the userit). The dependency isn't being put into the `DeleteImagesDto`, it's being put in the `ImagesService`. I invented `ImagesService` in absence of a concrete example by OP on how the `DeleteImagesDto` is being processed. In essence, the dependency should be injected in the class which contains the logic that depends on knowing the current user, which in my example is `ImagesService`.

Comment: @T.Sar: I've updated my answer to explicitly mention that the dependency should indeed not be injected into the DTO itself.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite more clear, now!